# How to remove inline breaks and categorise data in 2 separate columns?

Tags: r, sqlite

I have a "sample" data as -

```
{'data.frame':  33620 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ sample: chr  " Total Sample Size=\"128\"  IC-linebreak Sample Size from India=\"128\"   IC-linebreak  \nFinal Enrollment numb"| __truncated__ " Total Sample Size=\"120\"  IC-linebreak Sample Size from India=\"125\"   IC-linebreak  \nFinal Enrollment numb"| __truncated__ " Total Sample Size=\"74\"  IC-linebreak Sample Size from India=\"74\"   IC-linebreak  \nFinal Enrollment number"| __truncated__ " Total Sample Size=\"100\"  IC-linebreak Sample Size from India=\"100\"   IC-linebreak  \nFinal Enrollment numb"| __truncated__ ...
NULL}
```

The data in sample column has to be separated into 2 separate columns with col.names as - "Total Sample Size" and "Sample size from India" with their respective numeric values. This has to be done after removing the inline breaks.

The required data frame is supposed to be like -

```
| total sample size | sample size from India  |

| ----------------- | ----------------------- |

| 128               | 129                     |

| 130               | 131                     |
```

How can this be done ?
Thankyou for your help.

Sample data -

```
structure(list(sample = c(" Total Sample Size=\"128\"  IC-linebreak Sample Size from India=\"128\"   IC-linebreak  \nFinal Enrollment numbers achieved (Total)= \"\"   IC-linebreak  \nFinal Enrollment numbers achieved (India)=\"\"", 
" Total Sample Size=\"120\"  IC-linebreak Sample Size from India=\"125\"   IC-linebreak  \nFinal Enrollment numbers achieved (Total)= \"80\"   IC-linebreak  \nFinal Enrollment numbers achieved (India)=\"80\"", 
" Total Sample Size=\"74\"  IC-linebreak Sample Size from India=\"74\"   IC-linebreak  \nFinal Enrollment numbers achieved (Total)= \"\"   IC-linebreak  \nFinal Enrollment numbers achieved (India)=\"\"", 
" Total Sample Size=\"100\"  IC-linebreak Sample Size from India=\"100\"   IC-linebreak  \nFinal Enrollment numbers achieved (Total)= \"100\"   IC-linebreak  \nFinal Enrollment numbers achieved (India)=\"100\"", 
" Total Sample Size=\"250\"  IC-linebreak Sample Size from India=\"\"   IC-linebreak  \nFinal Enrollment numbers achieved (Total)= \"\"   IC-linebreak  \nFinal Enrollment numbers achieved (India)=\"\"", 
" Total Sample Size=\"80\"  IC-linebreak Sample Size from India=\"80\"   IC-linebreak  \nFinal Enrollment numbers achieved (Total)= \"80\"   IC-linebreak  \nFinal Enrollment numbers achieved (India)=\"80\""
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @RonakShah, I have edited in qstn. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use `strcapture` in base R -

```
strcapture('Total Sample Size="(\\d+)?"\\s+IC-linebreak Sample Size from India="(\\d+)?"', 
           df$sample, proto = list(Total_Sample_Size = numeric(), 
                                   Sample_size_from_India = numeric()))

#  Total_Sample_Size Sample_size_from_India
#1               128                    128
#2               120                    125
#3                74                     74
#4               100                    100
#5               250                     NA
#6                80                     80
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `extract` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    mutate(sample = trimws(sample)) %>% 
    extract(sample, into = c("Total Sample Size", "Sample Size from India"), 
           '^\\D+="(\\d+)\\D+="(\\d+)?.*', convert = TRUE)
```

-output

```
   Total Sample Size Sample Size from India
1               128                    128
2               120                    125
3                74                     74
4               100                    100
5               250                     NA
6                80                     80
```